# Divisibility and Primes

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-writing, divisibility

Suppose that $p,q,r$ are prime numbers and $p$ is odd. If $p\,|\,(2q+r)$ and $p\,|\,(2q-r)$, prove that $q=r$.

So I'm trying to use the definition of greatest common divisor to come up with two equations and make them equal each other.

So far I have, by D.I.C:

$$p\,|\,(2q+r)k + (2q-r)l,$$

where $k,l$ are integers.

I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

$p\mid [2q+r-(2q-r)]=2r\implies p|r$ as $p$ odd

$p\mid [2q+r+(2q-r)]=4q\implies p|q$ as $p$ odd

We can deduce something more than the proposition as $p,q,r$ are positive, right?

Comment: How did you arrive at the first 2 statements?

Comment: @IanMurphy, If integer $n$ divides $a,b,n$ must divide $ax+by$ where $a,b,x,y$ are integers, right? Now if integer $d|(ab)$ and $(d,b)=1,d$ must divide $a$